# What is the meaning of 心理活动 here?

Tags: meaning

I have this sentence at the beginning of a short 听力练习。

就一般心理活动而言，人们并非总是喜欢被别人称赞的。

心理 = mental, psychological 活动 = activity, action

Together 心理活动 just means 'mental movements'? = thoughts? Is that the meaning?

就一般心理活动而言， = My general thoughts on this matter are,

Comment: key: what goes through (sb's) mind, what is on (sb's) mind & Oxford: mental activity

Comment: Mental activity: http://www.iciba.com/%E5%BF%83%E7%90%86%E6%B4%BB%E5%8A%A8

Comment: Mr Drunken Master sir, would you kindly suggest something I could use in an English sentence? I doubt 'My mental activity in this regard, ' is very good Irish, or English for that matter! (read in an Irish accent). I like iciba, but their English is often atrocious!

Comment: If you are not convinced with iciba, you can still use Google to search and verify expressions you may come up with. Restrict your search to edu.cn or edu.tw sites [journals, universities] (site:edu.cn/site:edu.tw) and specify the words you have "心理活动" and "mental activity". You'll get results like this: http://terms.naer.edu.tw/detail/1307557/ or http://ccbs.ntu.edu.tw/FULLTEXT/JR-BJ010/bj83507.htm or http://zgglxb.chd.edu.cn/CN/abstract/abstract1809.shtml [click on the 参考文献 tab] If you want to come up with sth other than "activity" omit this word and see if you get other matches for 心理活动.

Answer (score 2):

You are right about 心理 and 活动 and 心理活动.

The key to understand this sentence is 就...而言, which means *with regards to/in terms of/based on*.

> 就一般心理活动而言 = With regards to the general psychological process, ...

The verbiage is not very precise in Chinese. My understanding is 'general' here refers to people in normal mental state.

The whole sentence means 'From psychological standpoint, (normal) people are not accepting praise at all time'.

Comment: I live in the hope that 背景理工大学出版社 will write good Chinese in the books I buy! Apparently not! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

心理活动 = something you are thinking or feeling at the moment you come across something, which you don't tell other people.

Your sample can be translated to : with regard to the personal feeling, not all people like being praised all the time.

Comment: Thanks for that! I would use 'With regard to my personal feeling, ...' but yeah, I like it! Upvote 哦！